# cambiar formato date en oracle sql 11g

Tags: sql, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

tengo un problema, tengo un trabajo que es de consultas de base de datos en oracle 11g, se crea la tabla empleado donde tiene 15 campos y tiene 2 campos con formato DATE.
el tema es que en los computadores de la facultad funciona perfecto el script, pero en el de mi casa, y en el de otros compañeros no funciona, ya que nos arroja el siguiente error:

> INSERT INTO empleado VALUES (11649964,'0','GALVEZ','CASTRO','MARTA','CLOVIS MONTERO 0260 D/202',1,'23417556','25273328','20121971','11081994',1515239,80,3,NULL)
>   Error report -
>   ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Esta es la tabla empleado:

```
(numrut_emp NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
dvrut_emp  VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
appaterno_emp VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
apmaterno_emp VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
nombre_emp VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
direccion_emp VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
id_estcivil NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
fonofijo_emp VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
celular_emp VARCHAR2(15),
fecnac_emp DATE,
fecing_emp DATE NOT NULL,
sueldo_emp NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,
id_comuna NUMBER(3),
id_categoria_emp NUMBER(1),
numrut_supervisor NUMBER(10),
CONSTRAINT pk_empleado PRIMARY KEY (numrut_emp));
```

y este es uno de los cientos de codigos de insert:

`INSERT INTO empleado VALUES (11649964,'0','GALVEZ','CASTRO','MARTA','CLOVIS MONTERO 0260 D/202',1,'23417556','25273328','20121971','11081994',1515239,80,3,NULL);`

se que utilizando to_date se soluciona el problema, pero son cientos de insert a los que tendría que hacerlo y estoy seguro que este problema se puede solucionar de raíz cambiando el formato de date en el programa(si en mi facultad se ejecuta bien, porque en mi pc no?), el problema es que no logro encontrar la forma.

***¿como puedo cambiar el formato de date en oracle 11g?***

Comment: Tal vez se deba al idioma en el que esta configurado es decir que en la de tu escuela sea ingles entonces toma bien el formato, pero el tuyo sea español entonces lo forma de diferente forma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes algunos problemas en tu sentencia de insert, veamos:

```
INSERT INTO empleado VALUES (11649964,'0','GALVEZ','CASTRO','MARTA',
                     'CLOVIS MONTERO 0260 D/202', 1, '23417556', '25273328', '20121971',
                     '11081994',1515239,80,3,NULL);
```

1. Falta de definición de columnas. Siempre que hagas un `insert` agrega las columnas a la clausula, si no lo haces, las columnas se asignan en el orden original en la tabla, el problema que tienes, es cuando agregas una nueva columna, "rompe" cualquier clausula de `insert` como ésta
2. Formato de fecha. Por lo que veo, las columnas de fecha serían la 10 y la 11 (viendo la sentencia de creación), los valores a insertar serían: `20121971` y `11081994`, entiendo que están en formato `ddmmyyyy`, el cual es un formato ambiguo, para el `insert` debes usar el formato `iso` es decir `yyyymmdd`

Finalmente, prueba algo así:

```
INSERT INTO empleado (numrut_emp, dvrut_emp, appaterno_emp, apmaterno_emp,  
                     nombre_emp, direccion_emp, id_estcivil, fonofijo_emp, 
                     celular_emp, fecnac_emp, fecing_emp, sueldo_emp, 
                     id_comuna, id_categoria_emp, numrut_supervisor)    
             VALUES (11649964,'0','GALVEZ','CASTRO','MARTA',
                     'CLOVIS MONTERO 0260 D/202', 1, '23417556', '25273328', '19711220', 
                     '19940811',1515239,80,3,NULL);
```

Un comentario extra, los datos `date` o `datetime` no tienen formato, el formato lo tiene las cadenas, en este caso la cadena de la clausula `insert`.